# a question about the direction of a flow of numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, markov-chains, markov-process, hidden-markov-models

I am trying to figure out if a stream of numbers i say more positive or more negative or neutral.

Let's say I have a stream of numbers that I can sample. I would like to estimate are these last x numbers positive, negative or neutral.

I am trying to figure out what area of math would help me to solve these types of questions.

Let's say I have a vector of numbers like this:

```
9, 3, 3, 3, 4, 7, 3, 8, 0, 4, 4, 5, 1, 10, 9, 0, 6, 6, 8, 2, 3, 9, 1, 0, 8, 4, 9, 7, 1, 5, 1, 10, 0, 10, 8, 9, 9, 3, 0, 10, 2, 1, 5, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 2, 3, 7, 9, 4, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 2, 7, 7, 2, 2, 10, 5, 10, 2, 10, 2, 1, 4, 0, 8, 2, 5, 1, 8, 0, 0, 7, 0, 8, 4, 8, 10, 9, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 7, 10, 3, 7, 0, 8, 3, 4
```

If I start at the 1st - 10th items;
are these ten numbers more positive, negative or neutral.

of if I start at item 21st - 31st items;
are those ten numbers more positive, negative or neutral.

I'd like to be able to choose X items from this vector, then estimate if they are positive, negative or neutral.

Is that clearer?

Comment: This should be a hypothesis-test. The hypothesis could be that the generator produces more positive numbers in the long run.  You can apply the same test for the hypothesis that the generator produces more negative numbers. The neutral case is most difficult. Both hypothesis must eventually be rejected that we can expect that we have this case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to clarify with a few examples.